# Probability of drawing a number smaller than the previous one in a urn of n balls

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations

Anne is playing the following game: She draws balls from an urn containing n balls labeled from 1 to n. The balls are drawn without replacement and with equal probability. The game ends as soon as she draws a ball with a smaller number than the previous one. Anne earns 1 Euro for each ball drawn.

(a) Let Xk be the indicator variable for 1 ≤ k ≤ n defined as follows: Xk = 1 if Anne wins at least k Euros, and 0 otherwise. Determine the density of Xk.

Solution proposal:
Let Ek be the event that Anne wins at least k Euros. We consider the sequence of n numbers that would result if Anne were to draw all the remaining balls from the urn even after the game ends. For such a sequence to yield a win of at least k Euros, the first k - 1 numbers must be sorted in ascending order. There are n choose (k-1) ways to select the set of the first k - 1 numbers, and for each selection, the order is uniquely determined. However, the remaining n - k + 1 numbers can be arranged in any order, which corresponds to (n - k + 1)! permutations.

Since all n! sequences are equally likely, the probability of Ek, denoted as Pr[Ek], can be calculated as follows:
Pr[Ek] = (n choose (k-1)) * (n - k + 1)! / n!

Simplifying the expression, we have:
Pr[Ek] = n! / ((k-1)! * (n - k + 1)! * n!) = 1 / (k-1)!

The density of the indicator variable fXk(x) is:
fXk(x) = 1 / (k-1!) for x = 1
fXk(x) = 1 - (1 / (k-1)!) for x = 0
0 otherwise.

I have the solution but I dont really understand how they have calculated it. Doesnt nCk-1 represent unordered set possibilities? Why do they have to be ascending?  Can anyone give me a intutive explanation? And also suggestions to find similar problems like these to practice? Is there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: *Why do they have to be ascending?* Because you want the probability that Anne wins at least $k$ Euros. If the first $k-1$ were not ascending, the process would have ended earlier, preventing Anne from winning $k$ Euros.

Answer (score 1):

Pick k numbers in a sequence. In order that each number is larger than the previous one, all k numbers must be sorted. There are k! arrangements so the probability is 1 / k!.

Anne wins exactly k euros if the first k-1 numbers are sorted but the last one is not the largest one, the probability is 1/(k-1)! * (k-1)/k or (k-1) / k!. The exception is k=n where she cannot draw an n+1st number, so the probability is k/k! instead.

Note that all the n-k numbers that are not drawn are irrelevant to the calculation.

Careful addition shows that Anne wins at least k euros with probability 1 / (k-1)!, this is easily shown by calculating the probability of at least k in the order k=n, k=n-1 etc.